# Copy custom list from one server to anothe server programatically sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

We are using sharepoint 2007,We have two site, both sites are on different server.
According to requirement we need to copy custom list from one server to another on daily/weekly basis.
We want to automate this process.
Is there any way by which we can do this programatically.

Thanks in advance,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 2):

1. For scheduling you can use SharePoint Timer Jobs.
2. For the second part, copying list, I am assuming you want to copy the List Items. You can use SharePoint List Web Service for submitting items to a remote server.

Comment: Hi Nitin,Thanks for giving reply.
Yes we need to copy list items on destination server site.
Do you have any code or reference link for the same ?

Comment: A quick google for following should give you lot of links - Add List Item using SharePoint List Web Service.

Comment: Reference Link - http://www.sharepointdynamics.net/2011/08/how-to-add-a-new-item-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-javascript-and-the-lists-asmx-web-service/. The link talks about doing from JavaScript but methodology would be same for you when calling from the timer job.